# Linux LD Linker Script - Duplicate Text Sections

Tags: linux, ld, osdev, linker-scripts

I have found this script at https://wiki.osdev.org/Linker_Scripts:

```
SECTIONS
{
  .text.start (_KERNEL_BASE_) : {
    startup.o( .text )
  }

  .text : ALIGN(0x1000) {
_TEXT_START_ = .;
    *(.text)
_TEXT_END_ = .;
  }

  .data : ALIGN(0x1000) {
_DATA_START_ = .;
    *(.data)
_DATA_END_ = .;
  }

  .bss : ALIGN(0x1000) {
_BSS_START_ = .;
    *(.bss)
_BSS_END_ = .;
  }
}
```

The entry:

```
.text.start (_KERNEL_BASE_) : {
    startup.o( .text )
  }
```

and

```
 .text : ALIGN(0x1000) {
_TEXT_START_ = .;
    *(.text)
_TEXT_END_ = .;
  }
```

will these sections not cause startup.o( .text ) to be written twice?

Comment: No, once `startup.o` .text segment is output, it will not be processed again.